# Empty the [recycle-bin]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I believe the tag [recycle-bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycle-bin)(194 questions) is not useful, because:

- **It contains many unrelated questions.** Most of them are about deleting files or putting them in the recycle bin, be it on Mac OSX, Google drive, Windows... I believe this is a 'meta-tag' because of this.

  Some examples:

  - [How to get url list of trash post in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421312/how-to-get-url-list-of-trash-post-in-wordpress)
  - [How to recover deleted Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525103/how-to-recover-deleted-xcode-project)
  - [Can I put files into LInux Trash with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254403/can-i-put-files-into-linux-trash-with-java)
  - [How to implement delete animation like iPhone's photo app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060675/how-to-implement-delete-animation-like-iphones-photo-app)
  - [Recycle the CONTENTS of a folder, but not the folder itself with either a Batch or VBS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510828/recycle-the-contents-of-a-folder-but-not-the-folder-itself-with-either-a-batch)
  - [Is there a way to retrieve the meta for a deleted Item (File/Folder) for Office365 OneDrive through REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792930/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-meta-for-a-deleted-item-file-folder-for-office3)

These tags are used for all kinds of different things, and I don't think they are terribly useful for finding or answering questions.

Some other similar tags I came across and which are of questionable usefulness are

- [garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/garbage) (200, most of these should be retagged to [garbage-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/garbage-collection)),
- [recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycle) (135),
- [recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycling) (100),

all of which are somewhat ambiguous, and can relate to various things.

Maybe more specific tags should be created for some of these tags, the questions edited ( and the bad ones closed ), and then the tags could be  **burninated** ?

> [image: Burninate Trashcan]

**What do YOU think ?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't really agree with the classification as ["meta-tag"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

> **If the tag can’t work as the *only* tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

Sure, if it stands alone, then it is utterly useless and probably belongs on SU. But then there are tons of popular tags that need another tag to disambiguate the meaning. I think about [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium), [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character), [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography), etc.

> **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

The second reason that this might be a meta tag would be that different people mean different things by this. I don't think this is the case, because if a system has a "recycle bin" then it means the same thing as on other systems. So the [recycle-bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycle-bin) and [trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trash) tags should be unified.

#### Other uses

Then there are the frameworks or libraries that use this. Those of course don't have a recycle bin in a traditional sense, but the concept is similar. I propose to retag them to [soft-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soft-delete). Possibly there are other more appropriate tags.

Comment: It might not be a 'meta-tag', but it is still applied to many unrelated questions. Even if [recycle-bin] and [trash] are unified, they will still be used for unrelated questions, and I don't think this is very useful. If there are other libs and frameworks which use this, why not create specific tags for those, such as [google-drive-trash].

Comment: "But then there are tons of popular tags that need another tag to disambiguate the meaning" - why would a _tag_ be needed here? What's the value of tagging e.g. a selenium question with `[trash]` as well? It's useless for categorization as it's far too broad, and the people who are able to answer the question will be the selenium experts, not the `[trash]` experts (I even doubt there can be any of those). If the question is about soft-deleting something in selenium, then this should be expressed _in the title_ which is entirely enough. A tag would just uselessly group a ton of trash questions.

Comment: [tag:soft-delete] sounds like a meta-tag if I ever saw one. Grouping things like that forces it to mean different things for different people. The Windows recycle bin and OSX trash and Wordpress trash all work in very different ways, some of which can be relevant to programmatically handling them.

Comment: @JonasCz Every tag has unrelated questions. That is why editing every question that you open/answer is necessary to keep the site clean. That is why there are badges for it (Refiner, Explainer, Illuminator). I don't think creating a bunch of recycle bin tags for every system that there exists is such a good idea. The concept is everywhere the same, but then I'm no expert in the specifics. Why would it be necessary to split it? Use [<lang>]+[<system>]+[recycle-bin] to make it clear what you're talking about.

Comment: @l4mpi I don't know why you would tag a question with [selenium] *and* [trash]. I don't see that they have anything to do with each other. My point was that [selenium] cannot be used alone. In fact, the excerpt says that other tags should be used on [selenium] questions. Too bad that nobody reads the excerpts or wikis.

Comment: @ssube [tag:soft-delete] is a very specific concept in the same way that [tag:model-view-controller] is one. Are concepts tags not allowed anymore? Have I missed something? I'm no expert in any of the recycle bins or trash cans, so I cannot say with certainty whether they can be grouped together. My hunch is in my answer. If you have domain knowledge about Windows' recycle bin or OSX's trash, please provide your own answer.

Comment: @ArtjomB Ok, missed that as I'm not a selenium expert. But reading the tag wiki, that seems to be an entirely different case - selenium in itself is not specific enough and you have to also tag a specific component of it (which makes the main tag a bit redundant, IMO). That's an entirely different scenario than [trash] because it already defines the topic and reels in experts who can answer. Furthermore, the set of required tags to chose from is very small. In the case of [trash], it only defines a very vague concept, and it does not help in getting answers or searching for specific questions.

Comment: @JonasCz FYI, there are currently 4 downvotes on my answer and 2 downvotes on your question.

Comment: That means that there are 4 upvotes on your answer :-)

Comment: @JonasCz This isn't going anywhere. 4 downvotes for you and 6 downvotes for me.

Comment: Ah well, it's only 150 questions anyway. But the tags [garbage] , [recycle] , and [recycling] still need to be cleaned up though.

Comment: The tags [recycle-bin] and [trash] were being used interchangably, so I synonymized them, if it were to be burninated, it is easier to burninate one tag directly, rather than multiple small tags. (cc @JonasCz)