# Tags [recycle],[recycling] are a muddle, should we disambiguate, retag and burninate them?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are currently tags [recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycle),[recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycling) with no tag definition. The term and the tags seem to get generically used for several distinct unrelated meanings:

1. Android recycler (a ViewGroup). There is an existing tag [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview), and [in 2017 there was also [recyclerview] which was aliased to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295916/lets-recycle-recyclerview)  (18.3K hits).

   - **Proposal**: keep using [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview) for that.
2. [**vector-recycling**, in R language](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) (repeating scalar or shorter vector arguments to give vector output)

   - **Proposal**: no tag needed. Untag [recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycle),[recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycling). Plaintext search for recycle|ed|ing is adequate. I am not proposing a tag [r-vector-recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-vector-recycling)
3. a) Recycling in ASP/C#/IIS/AppPool [application-pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-pool) and 3b) C#/WPF. (Are these two or more distinct things? Is the latter generic view-recycling in GUIs, hence similar to Android?)

   - **No idea. Some C# person needs to propose what do with these, and retag.**
4. Any other use-cases?
5. Not to be confused with the tags [[recycle-bin] and [trash]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288762/empty-the-trash-and-the-recycle-bin), which exist in multiple languages, CMSes and OSes.

   - **No proposal**: go discuss those two at the [existing proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288762/empty-the-trash-and-the-recycle-bin)

**Main proposal**: 
[recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycle),[recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycling) tags are not needed and should be burninated

Comment: [tag:recycler]? [tag:recycling]?

Comment: Title suggestion: Lets recycle the [recycler]

Comment: Title suggestion: Who recycles the [recycler]?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: yes I meant [recycle],[recycling]. Anyway we need some C# and Android people to propose what they want to do.

Comment: As to the title, I'm not into playful titles this time, because there are overlapping use-cases, we need people from those to figure out if any renamed/disambiguated tags are needed.

Comment: I am far from the strongest SME for [tag:r], but I think there's no need for a [tag:r-vector-recycling] tag. In my experience, the behavior of vector recycling is pretty simple and most questions relating to it either happen when 1) the asker doesn't realize recycling is happening (in which case they wouldn't know to use the tag), 2) vector recycling is the solution to the problem (again, the question wouldn't be tagged with it) or 3) the asker is trying to get it to work with another function, in which case the problem is with the other function, not with vector recycling

Comment: Re: C# IIS recycling - I'm not positive that we **need** the tag as such - "recycling the app pool(s)", while crucial, is basically the "have you tried turning it off and on again" of IIS. However, I'm also not positive that we **don't** need it, either. It could very easily be replaced with the more specific [tag:iis-recycle]. Anyone even remotely familiar with IIS would know what it meant.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar: fine, please post an answer, just set out the cons and pros. No we do not want a language-/tool/CMS/OS-specific tag 'X-recycle', then we'd get 1000 new tags for no particular reason. Is there anything important/ different/noteworthy about recycling in IIS, or object recycling in general that merits a tag? Unless someone can articulate a case for yes, then we don't need [recycle],[recycling].

Comment: I merged the two tags, they meant the same. Now if it is decided to burninate, we just need to burninate the one single tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao: but we still haven't reached decision on each of the separate use cases and which (if any) merit a tag. Can you post an answer to the questions I asked, even a partial answer?

Comment: I'll post one as soon as I find time to fix the tags.

Comment: [recycling] has since been merged into [recycle]

Comment: @Zoe: ok that's one less, but are any tags needed? Still not hearing any overall answer

Answer (score 1):

3a) Re the IIS questions: **No, tags are not needed for that**

Short version: IIS recycling is a specific thing that exists but I don't think there are enough questions to justify the tag.

Longer version:

Upon reflection, I don't think it's necessary to have a tag for IIS app pool recycling. There's a pedantic argument to be made that, as a concept, an [iis-recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iis-recycle) deserves to exist, but the fact of the matter is that I can only think of a handful of question that would justify having that tag:

1. What is recycling the app pools and what does it do? (tl;dr - turns it off and on again)
2. When should I recycle the app pools? (If your cached data is stale or if your site isn't working and you want to feel like you're helping)
3. Recycling the app pools didn't help, now what? (That sucks because now you have to understand your code)
4. I think I found a bug in app pool recycling (you didn't)

And that's literally every question in the world that I can possibly think of that might justify having one of these tags on. We don't need to keep it around for IIS, it can safely be removed from those questions.

Comment: For the 99% of us who know nothing about C#, IIS or AppPool, a) how is their recycling that much different or more noteworthy than Django, Java, Android et al. and b) can anyone articulate why any of these merit a generic tag [recycle]/[recycling]? (other than plaintext keyword search). If your conclusion to 3a) is 'No', can you put that on top of your answer? What about 3b) C#/WPF?

Comment: The major difference that I can tell from some cursory googling is that in IIS there's a rather prominent option in the UI inviting you to recycle your app pools, as opposed to the others where you can conceptually recycle workers or processes but there's not an actual feature/command that says "recycle my site" (I could very well be wrong about that). I don't know WPF off the top of my head, I'd have to take a look around.

Comment: but that's just how you configure the setting, so what. I'm asking **if the way 'recycling' actually works in IIS is so very much different or noteworthy**.

Comment: It's not a setting, it's an action taken by the user, but no, there's nothing special about it. It just stops and restarts your site with a couple considerations for gracefully ending processes.